# Как вертикально поставить кнопки telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет
Не могу понять как поставить кнопки вертикально. Они встают так, 1 большая сверху и две маленьких снизу, мне нужно чтобы они были вертикально, то есть одна кнопка сверху, одна по середине и одна снизу. Надеюсь вы поняли

```
elif message.text == 'Выбор' :
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Работа')
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Дом')
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton('Дерево')
        back = types.KeyboardButton('Меню')
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите слово', reply_markup = markup)
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [задать параметр `row_width=1`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/7588c9fb9fd96fddd8b762ecc4847b76f78229d6/telebot/types.py#L924):

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает

Comment: @ogloc, пожалуйста :)